# Emojis do not render well on Heroku with Pillow but they do locally

Tags: django, heroku, python-imaging-library

I am using Pillow 4.2 in a Django 1.10 application to insert some text containing unicode emojis over images. The whole thing runs on Python 2.7 for backward compatibility reasons.

Locally it works like a charm. By the way I am using `OpenSansEmojis.tff` for the font.

When I push my code on Heroku though, the emoji characters are not displayed properly and I get the "square" character instead (▯). That said, accented characters such as 'é', 'è', 'ç', etc. are all displayed correctly.

I should add that the function is run by a Celery 4.* worker (separate dyno on Heroku).

#### What I tried already

I tried to set `PYTHONIOENCODING` but it did not help.

I tried to use [the trick mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23025001/encoding-error-in-django-on-heroku/23794871#23794871) but it didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it was a bit hard to figure out but I think Heroku is running a [narrow build](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0261/) of Python whereas I am running a "wide" build on my laptop.

This explains why emoji characters are properly displayed locally but fail in production even with the exact same code and dependencies installed.

In order to force Heroku to use a "wide" build, I used the `Conda` buildpack instead of the default buildpack for python applications. Conda seems to run a wide build and I need it anyway because Pillow/PIL cannot be properly installed with the default buildpack.